# Why router is always using default values for Route Parameters, instead of provided ones?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What I am doing wrong that all of my valid URLs are being directed to HomeController and invalid URLs are correctly being rejected.

I have following controllers:

```
HomeController
ThisController
ThatController
MyController
```

Here is my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                    "StaticRoute", 
                    "My/Index", 
                    new { controller = "This", action = "Index" }

            routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", 
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

All of the following URLs being directed to "HomeController":

```
/  
/Home  
/Home/Index  
/This  
/This/Index  
/That
```

Following URL is correctly being directed to "ThisController":

```
/My/Index
```

Whereas following urls are correctly being 404ed:

```
/Home/NotExists  
/This/NotExists  
/His  
/Her/Index
```

Looks like default route is always using default values, not the Route Parameters. Is my understanding about Router wrong or doing some other mistake?

**EDIT**
All controllers have default undecorated Index methods, without parameters

Comment: What actions you have on the `ThisController`, `ThatController` `MyController` ?

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine and both `/This` and `/This/Index  ` will redirect to the `Index` method of `ThisController`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, you are right but this is the problem I am facing, both /This and /This/Index are being redirected to HomeController.Index()